# How to merge disjoint polygons into a single polygon in Postgis using Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-9.3

I have a table with polygon geometries. The polygons are separate to each other like the picture below:

[image]

I want to get a single polygon formed after merging these polygons using Postgresql. Below is the expected polygon:

[image]

Please ignore the buffer in boundaries of red polygon, it is just to make the picture clearer.

My polygon table has two columns, id and geom. I have tried using ST_Collect, ST_MakePolygon, and ST_ExteriorRing but using these I only get MULTIPOLYGON having these polygons as it is. I need a single polygon. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try st_concavehull https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConcaveHull.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use similar SQL to this

> ```
> SELECT 
> ST_ConcaveHull(
>       ST_Collect( ARRAY(
>                           select 
>                           "Poly"
>                           from table_name
>                           where "OBJECTID" in (5,15,2) 
>                           ) 
>                   ),0.99 
>               )
> ```

and add some pic to better illustrate

[image]

[image]